# Parsing JSON file to array, only puts last read value everywhere

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I have the following code that basically, reads a JSON file, then puts it in a multidimensional array.

```
let fs1 = require('fs');
let root1 = fs1.readFileSync('myFile.json');
let data1 = JSON.parse(root1);

for(index1 in data1){
    for(index2 in data1[index1]){
        console.log(index1)
        console.log(index2)
        console.log(data1[index1][index2])
        myArray[index1][index2] = data1[index1][index2]
    }
}
```

The problem is that myArray is being filled EVERYWHERE with the last value in the JSON file even the console.log shows the good values/indexes/etc...

I'm quite new is JS so any help is welcome :D

Thanks in advance!
Juan

EDIT:

Finally solved. The problem was in myArray declaration.
Before it was like:

```
let v = [];
for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
    v[i] = 0;
}
let myArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
    myArray[i]= v;
}
```

And apparently it's all by reference, so the last value I assigned to myArray while reading data1 updated all of them.
Changed to:

```
let myArray = {};
for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
    myArray[i]= new Array();
}
for (i = 0; i < n ; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < n ; j++){
        myArray[i][j]= new Array();
    }
}
```

And this works fine (probably there is some better solution
to initialize the array than this single + double for loop)

Thanks again guys! :D

Comment: `for...in...` is for objects and not for arrays

Comment: use for loop or forEach loop

Comment: I don't get it... data1 is Object so i iterate through it with for...in...
The values i'm displaying in console.log are good (everything is being read correctly). The problem is  myArray[index1][index2] = data1[index1][index2] stores the last value read from data1 in all positions

Comment: You never declare `index1` and `index2`.

Comment: Could you possibly provide more information on how the JSON data is structured?

Comment: The error must be in how you have initialised `myArray`. You did not provide that code, but I am quite sure you made a logical error in that initialisation code. Maybe you did `var myArray = Array(100).fill([])` or something similar? It would explain the behaviour you have...

Comment: I did it like this:
        let v = [];
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
  v[i] = 0;
 }
 let myArray = [];    
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
  myArray[i] = v;
 }

Comment: Could you please post you complete example with sample data to replicate scenario.
I think here problem is with initializing when you do for `(i = 0; i < n; i++){ myArray[i] = v; }` v is getting copied everywhere by reference not by value.

Comment: Solved!! Apparently, that was the problem! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to create some sort of object, of which contains some array(s)?

If so, you could do something like this?

### Edit

Having read through some of the comments and whatnot, your issue is that you keep overwriting the value of `myArrray[index1][index2]`, rather you should do something like my solution, **or** you could do some check within the outer loop, to see if `myArrray[index1]`, if not, then assign it to be an array or an object, then worry about the other keys, aka `index2`.

With the `map` approach, at least you don't have to worry about checking if `myArrray[index1]` is an array, because `map` will just return an array.

```js
const myArray = {};

// Object containing arrays example.
const dummyData1 = {
  'array1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'array2': [1, 2, 3, 4]
  // etc...
};

Object.keys(dummyData1).forEach(key => {
  myArray[key] = dummyData1[key].map(data => data);
});

console.log(myArray);


// Object containing objects example. 
const dummyData2 = {
  'object1': {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  },
  'object2': {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
  }
  // etc...
};

Object.keys(dummyData2).forEach(key => {
  myArray[key] = { ...dummyData2[key]};
});

console.log(myArray);


// Another example for the lols. 
const dummyData3 = {
  'arrayx': [1, 2, 3],
  'arrayz': [4, 5, 6]
  // etc...
};

Object.keys(dummyData3).forEach(key => {
  myArray[key] = [...dummyData3[key]];
});

console.log(myArray);
```

### Edit 2

Considering you can't seem to grasp the first coded example, to be fair, like you've said, you're new to JavaScript, so here's something that you may be able to understand as it's a lot more familiar to your example.

```js
const myArray = {};
const data1 = {
  'array1': {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  },
  'array2': {
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
    f: 6
  }
};



for (let index1 in data1) {
  myArray[index1] = myArray[index1] || [];
  for (let index2 in data1[index1]) myArray[index1].push(data1[index1][index2]);
}

console.log(myArray);
```

### Edit 3

Having learned that you come from a C++ background, maybe reading through pages such as [this](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-to-learn-JavaScript-after-a-C++-background) may be of some help?

Again, you're new to JavaScript, I won't make any assumptions regarding your skills or abilities to write JavaScript. Myself, originally I learned Java as my first language, so learning JavaScript wayback when was a little confusing to myself, an example being how `class` wasn't a thing back then, you had to define a class with a function, which wasn't a big deal, but it's just one of *those* things.

Comment: Mmmh, i'm trying to adapt that code to mine...actually index1 AND index2 are important cause myArray is filled partially with data1, then i complete it with
another json file (that will be data2) so yeah, i basically need all indexes

Comment: You can easily take the code I've provided and apply it to your specific use case without much hassle? Surely it would be a matter of copying the logic? If not, you could just make some function to manage it all for you? ... Etc... Either way, my example does copy **both** index1 **and** index2, I've just given them different names, aka ```key``` and ```data```.

Comment: I basically changed my code to your putting:
Object.keys(data1).forEach(index1 => {
  Object.keys(data1[index1]).forEach(index2 => {
        etc etc etc

and the result is the same...array contains the same value always... :/

Comment: I got that, myArray it's been already initialized (check my comment in the original post). Now i'm basically changing the values inside it, to those is data1...
I'm a c++ programmer, so something is odd for me with JS :/

Comment: Take a look at the second edit I've made, you can see that I've initialised ```myArray[index1]```, then you worry about ```myArray[index1][index2]```... Is it starting to make a bit more sense? Considering you come from a C++ background, I would've imagined JavaScript would be a breeze?

Comment: Glad to have helped!